# Show $\pi_1(SU(2)/H_8)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

Say $H_8$ is a quaternion group of order 8,

How should one think of the space $SU(2)/H_8$ even if $H_8$ is not a normal subgroup?

How do we show 
$$\pi_1(SU(2)/H_8)=H_8?$$

Comment: $SU(2)$ is a lie group, hence a manifold (or is a manifold, hence a Lie group, depends your perspective :) ).The action of quaternions produces an orbit space hence with induced topology by the natural projection you have a new topological space. So naturally you come up with the question of the fundamental group. If I recall correctly, in Hatcher's book you may find something useful about it (or something similar anyway).

Comment: $H_8$ doesn't need to be normal to define $SU(2)/H_8$: it's simply the set of left cosets of $H_8$. Normality is only required to define an appropriate group structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a discrete group $G$ acts [properly discontinuously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082834/properly-discontinuous-action-equivalent-definitions) on a path-connected space $X$, then the projection 
$$p:X\to X/G$$ 
is a covering map. For a reference, check Switzer's algebric topology text page 62, or in Hatcher, page 72. From here, applying the long exact sequence of a fibration to the covering map $p$ gives:
$$\cdots\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_1(G)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_1(X)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_1(X/G)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_0(G)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_0(X)\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\cdots$$
which gives us the short exact sequence:
$$0\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\pi_1(X)\xrightarrow{\ p_* \ }\pi_1(X/G)\xrightarrow{\ \ \partial }\pi_0(G)\cong G\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }0,$$
since $\pi_1(G)=0$ and $\pi_0(X)=0$. One can show that $\partial$ is a homomorphism in this case, and therefore by the first isomorphism theorem,
$$G\cong \frac{\pi_1(X/G)}{p_*(\pi_1(X))}.$$
In your case, we have:
$$H_8\cong\frac{\pi_1(SU(2)/H_8)}{p_*(\pi_1(SU(2)))}.$$
As explained by Max in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907927/quickest-self-contained-way-of-finding-pi-1-textsu2-and-pi-1-textso), $SU(2)\cong S^3$, so $\pi_1(SU(2))\cong \pi_1(S^3)$ which is trivial, and therefore
$$H_8\cong \pi_1(SU(2)/H_8).$$

Comment: @annieheart Happy to help, and no problem at all.

Comment: One thing I guess I should mention, thinking of $SU(2)$ as $S^3$, the group $H_8$ acts on $S^3$ by 90-degree rotations, so at least intuitively, this action should be properly discontinuous.

Comment: thanks I ask another new basic question you may know.